# How to use pager or term limit for taxonomy_get_tree($vid)?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, paging

How to use pager or how to limit terms, when using `taxonomy_get_tree($vid)`?

I have this code for terms generation:

```
<?php
$vid = 2;
$terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vid);   
$max_depth = (!isset($max_depth)) ? count($children[$vid]) : $max_depth;

foreach ($terms as $term) {
if ($term->depth == 0) 
{  
print "" .l("<b>Auto Insurance for &nbsp;</b> " .$term->name,'taxonomy/term/'.$term->tid, array('attributes' => array('title' => $term->name, ), 'html' => TRUE) ). "";

}}

?>
```

But there are thousands of terms or sub terms. Some pages are then loading more then 20 seconds. I need to improve this situation.

Can you advice me please? Do you know some solution? Pager, Jquery, Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter into your for each statement that counts the array index and terminates after X number of items.  That'd fix it.

Comment: Well, that sounds good. But can u show me exactly how? My PHP knowledge is very poor Thank you.